# MS test ordered test - How can I get it to run in a clear and easy way?

Tags: mstest

I am quite depressed by MS Test. I would like to create an integration test so I can check if my repository does all CRUD operations as expected. Therfor I created 3 test methods

1. Where I add data and read it again -> test suceeds if inserted item can be retrieved
2. Where I update the inserted item and read it again -> test suceeds if the retrieved item has the same key but changed data
3. Where I delete the inserted item and try to read it again -> test suceeds if item can't be retrieved.

The main reason why I want to do it in this way is to reduce the amount of test setup I have need.

The first idea was to add one test method which does every thing but if the test fails than in the third part I am not able to see, that the others suceeded.

That's why I tried the ordered test where it should be possible to say in which order the methods are called by the framework. This works as long as I use the test view which I usualy avoid. I am usualy use control + R + T but this will also execute each method in a random order and not in the defined one. Last but not least, it seems that I have to do additional work if I want to execute the ordered test on our build machine.

I can't understand why the methods are called in random order. I can't understand why I need an external file and can't easily define the order inside the code.

So my real questions are:
What am I doing wrong? Why does Microsoft adds such a strange functionality to it's tool? Why not say: [TestMethod("CRUD", 1)] and using parameteres of the attribute to define groups and the order.

It seems to me that Microsoft goes (again) a hard way in MS Test for something which could be done very easy.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the "why", I believe that this is done to prevent users of the test suite from introducing temporal dependencies to their tests.  It's a *unit* testing framework, and they mean that.

To explain what I mean, imagine that you had one test that was executed first, and that test had a side effect of creating a bunch of files in a specific directory.  You then had a second test that made use of these files.  Now, the ordering isn't just a convenience -- it's a necessity.  The second test makes no sense on its own.  I believe the harness writers would argue that these should either be a single test or (preferably) that you not use a unit testing suite to do tests like this.

As to what you're doing 'wrong', I don't know that you're doing anything wrong.  I think you're just trying to use the tool in a way that the authors didn't intend.  Personally, if I were writing an integration test suite for CRUD operations, I wouldn't use MS Test or a unit testing framework at all.  I'd either use a tool designed to do such a thing or else I'd write a little application that exercised your data access DLLs by performing the CRUD operations and reporting on the results.

Your own home rolled utility could be included in your solution for quick running as startup project, invoked by your build, etc.  If you wanted to put a bit of extra time into it, you could even have it generate a little report or make its output conform to the same output as MS Test (those test XML files).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have never seen MS Test as a unit testing framework, even this word is used quite often in the UI. I mean, we have the possibility to attach data bases, check the behaviour of the applications UI and I need to use files when ever I want to create prameterized tests. That sounds more like integration and system tests than tiny and easy to execute Unit Tests like they are described in theory. Don't get me wrong but now I understand what Roy Osherove tried to say when he wrote: "MS test is like IE6"

Comment: Well, I personally use it only for unit testing, but I do see your point.  It seems odd that they'd have this philosophy and then allow you to do things like require files and whatnot for tests to run.  I came from an xUnit background, so there are some annoyances with MS Test.  For what you're doing (ordered tests, it might be worth seeing if NUnit or MBUnit will support your test orderings -- you might like working with them better anyway... think of them as Firefox and Chrome to MSTests's IE6 :) )